# How can I remove decimal number in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

For my command cooldown system, I used this Code:

```js
if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
  cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
}
const current_time = Date.now();
const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
const cooldown_amount = command.cooldown * 1000;
if (time_stamps.has(message.author.id)) {
  const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;
  if (current_time < expiration_time) {
    const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;
    return message.reply(`${time_left.toFixed(1)}s cooldown`).then((msg) => {
      setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 3000);
    });
  }
}
time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);
```

That for example returns: '4.2s cooldown'.
I want to know how can I remove the decimal number:
'4s cooldown'.

**Notes:** I am using discord.js v13 and node.js v16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove decimal number you can round a number you are sending using [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) or also you can use [`Math.trunc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) to simply remove it as @MZPL said!

Answer (score 1):

Change the following

```
return message.reply( `${time_left.toFixed(1)}s cooldown`)
```

to

```
return message.reply( `${time_left.toFixed()}s cooldown`)
```

You can also use [Math.trunc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) to achieve that.